# What‘s the irreducible basis of $N$ atoms in $m$ states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, atomic-physics

If there are N states, and each of the N atoms occupies one state, then, the irreducible basis can be just obtained from the N permutation group. But if there are only m($m<N$) states, How can I determine the irreducible state of this system? I have seen the result of 3 atoms system from a [paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.70.023820). If two atoms are in the same state, then, the irreducible basis are ($i,j=1,2,3, i\not=j$)
\begin{equation}
\vert s_{ijj} \rangle=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\vert ijj \rangle + \vert jij \rangle + \vert jji \rangle), \\
\vert b_{ijj} \rangle=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(2\vert ijj \rangle - \vert jij \rangle - \vert jji \rangle),\\
\vert c_{ijj} \rangle=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert ijj \rangle - \vert jji \rangle)
\end{equation}
But I don't understand how can I get it, nor the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a math problem of reducing a representation of $S_3$, so here's a sketch of how to proceed.

1. Obtain the $3\times 3$ matrices of the 6 elements of $S_3$  For instance using $P_{12}\vert ijj\rangle=\vert jij\rangle$ and similarly on the other elements of your original basis you can construct the matrix elements of $P_{12}$ and, systematically using all elements in $S_3$, all the matrices of the permutations.  For instance:
   $$
   P_{12}= \left(
   \begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{array}
   \right)\, ,\qquad 
   P_{132}=\left(
   \begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
   \end{array}
   \right)
   $$
2. Decompose the resulting representation into irreducibles using orthogonality of characters.  In your specific case the 3-dimensional representation will contain $\{3\}\oplus \{2,1\}$, i.e. the 1-dimensional symmetric and 2-dimensional mixed symmetry irreps.  The character table for $S_3$ is: 
   $$
   \begin{array}{c|ccc}
   & \{3\} &\{2,1\} & \{1,1,1\}\\
   \hline
   \{3\}& 1 & 1 & 1 \\
   \{2,1\}& -1 & 0 & 2 \\
   \{1,1,1\}& 1 & -1 & 1 
   \end{array}
   $$
   Thus to verify the $\{2,1\}$ occurs once in your 3-dimensional rep use
   $$
   \frac{1}{6}\left(\chi^{\{2,1\}}(\{3\})\times 2\times 0 +
   \chi^{\{2,1\}}(\{2,1\})\times 3\times 1+\chi^{\{2,1\}}(\{1,1,1\})\times 1\times 3\right)
   =1
   $$
3. Using Young symmetrizers for each irrep, obtain by projection *one* state in each irrep.
4. This is enough for $\{3\}$ since it is 1-dimensional.  For $\{2,1\}$ you will get from the symmetizer only of the 2 states.  The second state can be found by acting on the first with any permutation that dies not leave this first state invariant.  There will remain to orthonormalize, and you're done.
5. All the steps above generalize to more complicated cases.

Comment: Thanks! I think this clears my minds a lot. I have used the Young symmetrizers to get the irreducible basis ${\vert ijj \rangle + \vert jij \rangle + \vert jji \rangle, \vert ijj \rangle - \vert jij \rangle, \vert ijj \rangle - \vert jji \rangle}$ from the original basis ${\vert ijj \rangle, \vert jij \rangle, \vert jji \rangle}$.  It's the same with the basis within my question under some linear transformation. However, I'm a little confused with the "Part 2" of your answer. I feel like you've taken the "{3},{2,1},{1,1,1}" as both irreducible representations and symmtry elements. Am I wrong?

Comment: They irreps and conjugacy classes are both labelled by partitions.  So here the 3 transposition are in the class $\{2,1\}$, the two 3-cyles in $\{3\}$ and the unit in $\{1,1,1\}$... and you're right you'll likely get a different basis for your $\{2,1\}$ but you can reduce it by recomputing the explicit matrices (now $2\times 2$) and choose to digonalize one transposition.  In $S_3$ the basis element are usually chosen to diagonalize $P_{12}$.  See also discussions of the Yamanouchi basis.

Comment: I think I'm gonna need more practice in determining the charaters. And could you recommend a book coverring the topic of Yamanouchi basis? I have never seen this in a book where I learned the Permutation groups before. Thank you!

Comment: Tung, Wu-Ki. Group theory in physics: an introduction to symmetry principles, group representations, and special functions in classical and quantum physics. World Scientific Publishing Co Inc, 1985 and also Chen, Jin-Quan, Jialun Ping, and Fan Wang. Group representation theory for physicists. World Scientific Publishing Co Inc, 2002 or Hamermesh, M. "Group theory." Reading, Mass (1962): 368. The last two discuss the Yamanouchi basis.  Chen is best but much more involved.